# How to select xml node value from a table column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have an sql table  column of text datatype having xml value in it.When I tried to select,it is giving a blank value.could someone help me on this?

**Table Structure**

```
Sid (int) | xmlresults (text) | recivedDate (Datetime)
```

**Query Used to retrieve**

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (N'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS NS)
SELECT
X.S.value('(NS:examinationDate)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as xmlvalue
FROM examinationresults er
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(xmlresults AS XML)) AS [XML](xmlresults)
CROSS APPLY [XML].xmlresults.nodes('/NS:NewExamResults/NS:Table1') AS X(S)
where  er.sid='8596123'
```

**XML Data**

```
<NewExamResultsType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NewExamResults xmlns="urn:ex.likeexam.com">
    <Table>
      <rowCount>1</rowCount>
    </Table>
    <Table1>
      <StudId>9447524123</StudId>
      <examinationDate>26/10/2019</examinationDate>
      <VerificationDate>111111111</VerificationDate>
      <examiner>Williams</examiner>
      <ExamResults>
        <ExamResult>
          <ExamCode>110</ExamCode>
          <StudName>Tony K</StudName>
          <StudCode>K</StudCode>
        </ExamResult>
      </ExamResults>
    </Table1>
  </NewExamResults>
</NewExamResultsType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace URIs `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` and `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` don't appear to be referenced in your example document. The important namespace URI is `urn:ex.likeexam.com` in which the `NewExamResults` node and all of its children reside. Try the following query instead...

```sql
with xmlnamespaces (
  N'urn:ex.likeexam.com' as le
)
select convert(date, table1.value(N'(le:examinationDate/text())[1]', N'varchar(10)'), 103) as examinationDate
from examinationresults
cross apply (select cast(xmlresults as xml)) c1(xmlValue)
cross apply xmlValue.nodes(N'/NewExamResultsType/le:NewExamResults/le:Table1') c2(Table1)
where sid='8596123';
```

Comment: It is working now.Need to include datetime instead of date.Thanks a lot.